# Is it possible to place an imageView in a class that extends View?

Tags: android

Is it possible to place an imageView in a class that extends View in android?
If possible please give me a sample code.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense.  All of the Layoout classes extend ViewGroup, so yes you can place ImageViews in them...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom view that contains an `ImageView` (and presumably some other items), you probably just want to extend a `ViewGroup`, such as a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) rather than directly extending `View`.

See the "[Compound Controls](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound)" section of the Custom Components page on the Android Developers' site.