# View class in ImageView

Tags: android

i have develop one application in which i want to play gif animation.
for that i have refer [this](http://www.anddev.org/how_to_play_gif_file_in_android-t3492.html)

**CODE**

```
public class GIFDemo extends GraphicsActivity {
ImageView imageView1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    imageView1  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);



}
private static class GIFView extends View{

    Movie movie,movie1;
    InputStream is=null,is1=null;
    long moviestart;
    long moviestart1;
    public GIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.border_gif);

        movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

         if (moviestart == 0) {   // first time
             moviestart = now;

         }
         if(moviestart1==0)
         {
             moviestart1=now;
         }

         int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration()) ;
        // int relTime1=(int)((now - moviestart1)% movie1.duration());

         movie.setTime(relTime);
        // movie1.setTime(relTime1);
         movie.draw(canvas,10,10);
         //movie1.draw(canvas,10,100);
         this.invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

Main :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

so problem is i want to set class `GIFView` in `Imageview` so i have refer post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832150/is-it-possible-to-place-an-imageview-in-a-class-that-extends-view)
but not get proper example. so can you give me proper example and explanation that **how can i set view in ImageView**

Thanks
nik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is meaningful to 'set the view' of an `ImageView` (in the way you are suggesting), and I don't think you even need an `ImageView` in this case. You have implemented a custom `View` that is able to draw a GIF without any dependency on the `ImageView` class - you just have to use it!

With minimal changes, assuming the `GIFView` works, you can just instantiate a `GIFView` and then add it to the main layout. Let your `onCreate` be as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // let your LinearLayout have an id of 'container'
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    GIFView gifView = new GifView(this);
    container.addView(gifView);

}
```

You can get rid of the ImageView from the layout entirely and just use your `GIFView` that was instantiated in code. Alternatively, you can make your `GIFView` a standalone (non-inner) class and add it to your XML layout by specifying the full package name, e.g.

```
<com.nik.view.GIFView
  id="@+id/gifview"
  ... />
```

You would also need to write the view constructor `GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` because that is the one that is expected when using XML.